# Kubernetes - Controller 0's connection to broker was unsuccessful

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up Kafka on Kubernetes, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

The full error is:

```
[2022-06-29 12:17:11,732] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] 
Controller 0's connection to broker kafka-service:29092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect within 30000 ms
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:293)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:246)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

Pod Definition:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    app: kafka
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9092
    env:
    - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
      value: zoo1:2181
    - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
      value: "0"
    - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
      value: "LISTENER_INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092"
    - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
      value: "LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-service:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka-service:9092"
    - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
      value: "LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
    - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
      value: "LISTENER_INTERNAL"
    - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
      value: "1"
    - name: KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE
      value: "10485760"
    - name: KAFKA_MAX_MESSAGE_BYTES
      value: "10485760"
    - name: KAFKA_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES
      value: "10485760"
```

Service - I've also tried using ClusterIP but the error stays:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
spec:
  type:  NodePort
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
    - name: kafka1
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
    - name: kafka2
      port: 29092
      targetPort: 29092
```

Any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Given that your advertised listeners are the exact same service name, then you do not need both of them on different ports. Instead, you could have "internal" within the pod, and "external" across namespaces

e.g. when using `default` namespace.

```
- name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
  value: "LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka-service:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka-service.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"
```

Also will want to add both ports

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 9092
  - containerPort: 29092
```

Unclear what your error is being logged from, but seems like you should be using an address closer to `kafka-service.svc.cluster.local:9092` - ref [Kubernetes DNS docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

---

Alternatively, https://strimzi.io has very in-depth documentation about running and using Kafka on Kubernetes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! But shouldn't i be able to connect to port 29092 nontheless? Given that in the KAFKA_LISTENERS im exposing that port? 
Still, with only one Listener the pod initializes correctly, that being port 9092, if I try to add one more Listener on port 29092 the problem persists.

Comment: `containerPort` is what exposes the pod. You've only set that to 9092, but your logs are saying the client is using 29092, which is not exposed

Comment: Just tried your config, error still persists. Funny enough, if i change kafka-service:29092 to localhost:29092 the error no longer appears.

Comment: Change it where? You've still not clarified what is logging that output. I've personally not defined a Kafka Pod/Service manually. Operators (such as Strimzi) are what I use

Comment: In the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS : "LISTENER_INTERNAL://localhost:29092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka-service.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"

Comment: Sure, connecting to `localhost:29092` ought to work in the same pod, depending on your network layer (or just for processes within that container). But within the default namespace, the other address should work as well